# onclick action after removeChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $intro_header;?></h1>
    <p>
      <?php echo $intro_tekst;?>
    </p>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader1" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv1').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item1;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader2" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv2').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item2;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader3" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv3').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item3;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader4" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes4'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv14').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item4;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv1"> </div>
    <div id="mydiv2"> </div>
    <div id="mydiv3"> </div>
    <div id="mydiv4"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close1">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item1;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item1;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage"><img src="<?php echo $image_item1;?>"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close2">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item2;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item2;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage"><img src="<?php echo $image_item2;?>"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close3">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item3;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item3;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage"><img src="<?php echo $image_item3;?>"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes4">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close4">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item4;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item4;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage"><img src="<?php echo $image_item4;?>"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--   
    <div id="onder"></div>
    -->
</div>
```

I am showing and hiding newboxing with succes. The only thing is that I want a closing mark within the div. I have made one but when I click it the show/hide function is not working anymore. I searched the past two days without any luck.

Here is the javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document

function showonlyone(thechosenone) {    
    $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") === thechosenone) {
            $(this).show(200);
        } else {    
            $(this).hide(600);    
        }    
    });    
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close1').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
     document.getElementById('close2').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
     document.getElementById('close3').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
         document.getElementById('close4').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
};
```

The testsite is on www.http://fitter.byantoinette.nl/

```js
    function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
      $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") === thechosenone) {
          $(this).show(200);
        } else {
          $(this).hide(600);
        }
      });
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('close1').onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
          .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
      };
      document.getElementById('close2').onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
          .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
      };
      document.getElementById('close3').onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
          .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
      };
      document.getElementById('close4').onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
          .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
      };
    };
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $intro_header;?></h1>
    <p>
      <?php echo $intro_tekst;?>
    </p>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader1" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv1').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item1;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader2" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv2').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item2;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader3" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv3').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item3;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
      <div>
        <a id="myHeader4" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes4'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv14').offset().top}, 'slow');">
          <?php echo $header_item4;?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv1"></div>
    <div id="mydiv2"></div>
    <div id="mydiv3"></div>
    <div id="mydiv4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close1">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item1;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item1;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage">
          <img src="<?php echo $image_item1;?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close2">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item2;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item2;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage">
          <img src="<?php echo $image_item2;?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close3">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item3;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item3;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage">
          <img src="<?php echo $image_item3;?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes4">
    <div class="fragment">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="close4">x</div>
        <div id="newtekst">
          <h1><?php echo $header_item4;?></h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo $artikel_item4;?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="newimage">
          <img src="<?php echo $image_item4;?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--   
    <div id="onder"></div>
    -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the snippet editor and tidy your code. Also you use a horrific mix of DOM, jQuery and inline script. Please first move the scripts out of the links (`javascript:` label is not even needed) For example give the links a class and add one event handler to take a data-divID attribute to show. Also use a loop in your PHP to not have such long code. They all behave the same so one loop is enough

Comment: For example: `$(function() {
      $('.close').on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).closest("whatparentyouwanttoclose").hide();
      });      });` which will hide the thing instead of REMOVING it which is not what you want is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, as mplingjan says, please clean your code.
I did it for you and I changed your code in some sections to make it work.
I took your first and second code. The problem was in removing elements.
Don't forgot to change indexed variables to arrays. I used array instead,
     `$header_item1,2,3,4 -> $header_item[]`

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="buttons">
        <h1>
            <?php echo $intro_header;?>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <?php echo $intro_tekst;?>
        </p>
        <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
        <div class="strip">
            <div>
                <a id="myHeader<?=$i?>" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes<?=$i?>'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv<?=$i?>').offset().top}, 'slow');">
                    <?php echo $header_item[$i];?>
                    <!-- change $header_item1,2,3,4 to array of $header_item -->
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
        <div id="mydiv<?=$i?>">
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
    <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes<?=$i?>">
        <div class="fragment">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="close<?=$i?>">
                    x
                </div>
                <div id="newtekst">
                    <h1>
                        <?php echo $header_item[$i];?>
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $artikel_item[$i];?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="newimage">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_item[$i];?>"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!--   
<div id="onder"></div>
-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
        $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
              if ($(this).attr("id") === thechosenone) {
                  $(this).show(200);
              }
              else {
                   $(this).hide(600);
              }
         });
    }


$(function(){
    <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
        $('#close<?=$i?>').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.newboxes').hide(); 

        });
    <?php } ?>
});

// window.onload = function(){
//     document.getElementById('close1').onclick = function(){
//         this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
//         .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
//         return false;
//     };
//      document.getElementById('close2').onclick = function(){
//         this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
//         .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
//         return false;
//     };
//      document.getElementById('close3').onclick = function(){
//         this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
//         .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
//         return false;
//     };
//          document.getElementById('close4').onclick = function(){
//         this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
//         .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
//         return false;
//     };
// };

</script>
```

**BUT**
this is just changing your code to work, but not my preferred code, the below code is tunned up in some sections. for example, when you have the power of JQuery, no need to use ID in 90% of implementations.
check this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="buttons">
        <h1>
            <?php echo $intro_header;?>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <?php echo $intro_tekst;?>
        </p>
        <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
        <div class="strip">
            <div>
                <a class="headerLink" data-boxId="newboxes<?=$i?>">
                    <?php echo $header_item[$i];?> <!-- change $header_item1,2,3,4 to array of $header_item -->
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
        <div id="mydiv<?=$i?>">
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php foreach([1,2,3,4] as $i) { ?>
    <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes<?=$i?>">
        <div class="fragment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="closer">
                    x
                </div>
                <div id="newtekst">
                    <h1>
                        <?php echo $header_item[$i];?>
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $artikel_item[$i];?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="newimage">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_item[$i];?>"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!--   
<div id="onder"></div>
-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){
        $('.headerLink').click(function(){
            $('.newboxes').hide(600);
            $('#' + $(this).attr('data-boxId')).show(200);
        });

        $('.closer').click(function(){
            $(this).cloesest('.newboxes').hide(600);
        });
});


</script>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I am pretty new to javascript as you can see. Can you please show me how to change indexed variables to arrays. I am now using this: '$header_item1 = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_item1')); '. header_item1 is coming from a xml form_field. I am using joomla. I can't get right. There are two more things that should be implemented: Onclick on the $header_item (the page should scroll down to #newboxes) and Onclick close (the page should scroll up to #button).

Comment: about other problems, I think rules of stackoverflow needs you to make another question, because it's different problem. your current question is about running onclick after removeChild (you said in header). asking another question helps people with same problem to find your question and the answer.

Comment: If you have no access to source of indexed variables, you can add this PHP code at first line: <?php header_item[1] = header_item1; header_item[2] = header_item2; ... ?> and do this for all other indexed variables. you can use eval() function too, but because of security reasons, many servers disable this eval() function on their servers. although I used array for beautify codes, using them is optional.

Comment: Hello Armin, In my code there is a line: $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydiv2').offset().top}, 'slow');, This takes the browser to the top of the opening div. In the answer I got they left the code behind. Therefore my question how te intergrate this in the answer I got. It is therefore not a new question. I am going to try your answer and I hope you can help me with the scrolling issue. Thanks.

Comment: It worked! There is a little mistake in the code:  $('.closer').click(function(){$(this).cloesest('.newboxes').hide(600);});. It has to be .closest.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickSmits, I wrote it in editor and I didn't test it. If the answer is correct let me know with green success tick, and if is there other problems let me know too.

Comment: @PatrickSmits, But you removed the correct answers check, Is ther any other problems?

Comment: I am sorry for my late reaction, but the code is up and running. I don't know what you mean by correct answers check.

Comment: @Patrick Smits, When you got your correct answer on Stackoverflow, you had to accept the answer by check it as `CORRECT ANSWER` ( a gray CHECKMARK under score of my answer, just click on it to change it to green), then other people can know which answer works. this shows that you found my answer helpful. ok?

Comment: Dear @PatrickSmits you forgot to mark my answer as true answer

Comment: I didn't forget it, but i can't find the right place to do so. Gray checkmark? Can't find it. Wait, this one?